# Is the attached digital camera on the top have the same magnification than visible in eyepiece?

Tags: microscopy

There are some microscopes with digital camera system attached to the top. But does it include or bypass eyepiece magnification?

E.g. 40x objective lens and 10x eyepiece making the total magnification of an image to 400x. Would I have the same magnification in digital camera image? If not, it's better to attach camera directly into eyepiece then?

---

Lets say for example AmScope SM-X series such as AmScope SM-1TNX-144A-3M ([current best microscopes for coins reviews](http://bestcompoundmicroscopes.com/best-microscopes-for-coins-reviews/)) or SM-2TZ-9M which is ideal to capture still images and record videos.

[image: microscope with digital camera system]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But does it include or bypass eyepiece magnification?

As the camera in the included image is clearly not looking through either of the eyepiece, it obviously doesn't include magnification due to those eyepieces. The camera likely has its own lens, however, that may provide a similar overall effect. For example, it looks like most of the AmScope cameras include a 0.5x reduction lens, which is probably necessary to get the image from the objective to fit on the (relatively small) image sensor.

> If not, it's better to attach camera directly into eyepiece then?

When you use a camera with a microscope like this, the camera generally takes the place of the eyepiece. That is, you remove the eyepiece first, and the camera fits into 23.2mm or 30mm ID tube where the eyepiece was. You should get about the same results this way as you would using the camera port.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think in this [article](http://www.aurelm.com/2014/03/09/diy-smartphone-adapter-for-microscope-photography/), smartphone camera is on top of the eyepiece, doesn't seems to replace the eyepiece, but I may be wrong. So does camera takes the place of the eyepiece only to kind of microscopes which is mentioned in original question (AmScope) or it depends?

Comment: It depends on your setup. You can obviously hold a small smartphone camera up to the eyepiece, which is more or less what the author of your linked page did, or you can use a camera designed for microscopy, or you can use a DSLR with an adapter.